# How do you get the snapshot of UIScreen from Under a displayed keyboard?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to get a snapshot of UIScreen under the keyboard? Perhaps this is possible using CALayer?

Comment: Try capturing the window. The keyboard should be on a different window than the rest of the app.

Comment: The key window includes the keyboard, is there a window I can just get without going through indexes?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
UIView* snapshotView = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO];
```

The key window is the window which includes the first responder, which is accepting the keyboard input.

If you need a snapshot in the form of an image, use `drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:` instead of `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:`.

Comment: My question asked if there was a name for the window that doesn't include the keyboard(which would be the first responder in this case). It's liking like I might have to iterate through the windows and figure this out.

Comment: @coolio The keyboard resides in a window of its own. It does not appear in any of your windows. The key window does not include the keyboard.